# Isomorphism in newtype

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand State newtype and I'm struggling with this explanation of the isomorphism in a book:

> Newtypes must have the same underlying representation as the type they wrap, as the newtype wrapper disappears at compile time. So the function contained in the newtype must be isomorphic to the type it wraps. That is, there must be a way to go from the newtype to the thing it wraps and back again without losing information.

What does it mean applied to State newtype?

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

That explanation "there must be a way to go from the newtype to the thing it wraps and back again" isn't clear.

Also, can you please say, where there is an isomorphism in this examples, where is not and why.

```
type Iso a b = (a -> b, b -> a) 

newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

sumIsIsomorphicWithItsContents :: Iso a (Sum a) 
sumIsIsomorphicWithItsContents = (Sum, getSum)

(a -> Maybe b, b -> Maybe a) 

[a] -> a, a -> [a]
```

Comment: "What does it mean applied to State newtype?" -- The `State` constructor goes in one direction, and the `runState` function goes in the opposite one. `runState . State = id`, and `State . runState = id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement you quote makes no mention of `State` specifically. It is purely a statement about `newtype`s. It is a little misleading in referring to "the function contained in the newtype" because there is no requirement for the type wrapped by a `newtype` to be a function type - although this is the case for `State` and many other commonly used types defined by `newtype`.

The key thing for a `newtype` in general is exactly as it says: it has to simply wrap another type in a way that makes it trivial to go from the wrapped type to the wrapping one, and vice versa, with no loss of information - this is what it means for two types to be isomorphic, and also what makes it completely safe for the two types to have identical runtime representations.

It's easy to demonstrate typical `data` declarations that could not possibly fulfil this. For example take any type with 2 constructors, such as `Either`:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

It's obvious that this is not isomorphic to either of its constituent types. For example, the `Left` constructor embeds `a` inside `Either a b`, but you can't get any of the `Right` values this way.

And even with a single constructor, if it takes more than one argument - such as the tuple constructor `(,)` - then again, you can embed either of the constituent types (given an arbitrary value of the other type) but you can't possibly get every value.

This is why the `newtype` keyword is only allowed for types with a single constructor which takes a single argument. This always provides an isomorphism, because given `newtype Foo a = Foo a`, then `Foo` constructor and the function `\Foo a -> a` are trivially inverses of each other. And this works the same for more complicated examples where the type constructor takes more type arguments, and/or where the wrapped type is more complex.

Such is exactly the case with `State`:

```
newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (a, s)}
```

The functions `State` and `runState` respectively wrap and unwrap the underlying type (which in this case is a function), and clearly are inverse to each other - therefore they provide an isomorphism.

Note finally that there is nothing special here about the use of record syntax in the definition - although it's very common in such cases in order to have an already-named "unwrapping" function. Other than this small convenience there is no difference from a `newtype` defined without record syntax.

To step back a little: `newtype` declarations are very similar to `data` declarations with a single constructor and a single argument - the difference is mainly in performance, as the keyword tells the compiler that the two types are equivalent so that there is no runtime overhead of conversion between the two types, which there otherwise would be. (There is also a difference with regard to laziness but I won't mention that, except here for completeness.) As for why do this rather than just use the underlying type - that's to provide extra type safety (there are 2 different types here for the compiler even though they're the same at runtime), and also allows typeclass instances to be specified without attaching those to the underlying type. `Sum` and `Product` are great examples here, as they provide `Monoid` instances for numeric types, based on addition and multiplication respectively, without giving either the undeserved distinction of being "the" Monoid instance for the underlying type.

And something similar is at work with `State` - when we use this type we signal explicitly that we're using it to represent state manipulation, which wouldn't be the case if we were just working with ordinary functions that happen to return a pair.

Comment: One important reason not to just use the underlying type is if you need something recursive. `newtype Fix f = In {out :: f (Fix f)}` is a classic example. The compiler would reject `type Fix f = f (Fix f)`.